# How can I make my 'Label' object have an attribute 'get'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code is showing the AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'. I've consumed all available resources around that I could get in contact with and found nothing to do. If a person can take the minute to help me I'll be very happy. The error is at line 67 which say: `Email = Label(root, text='Email/USER ID', font = ('consolas',13))`. Arigato

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector


global root
root = Tk()

root.geometry("350x450")
root.title("LOGIN")
root.resizable(0,0)

j=0
g=0
for i in range(100):
    c = str(222222+g)
    Frame(root, width=10, height=450,bg="gray").place(x=j, y=0)
    j = j + 10
    g = g + 1

Frame(root, width=250, height=350).place(x=50, y=50)

#============VARIABLES==========
Email = StringVar()
Password = StringVar()
#===============================

#Label Username/Email
Email = Label(root, text='Email/USER ID', font = ('consolas',13))
Email.place(x=80, y=170)
e = Entry(root, width=20, font = ('consolas',13))
e.place(x=80, y=200)

#Label password
Password = Label(root, text='Password', font = ('consolas',13))
Password.place(x=80, y=230)
e1 = Entry(root, width=20, font = ('consolas',13), show = '*')
e1.place(x=80, y=260)
stayButton = Checkbutton(root, text = "Remember Password")
stayButton.place(x=80, y=300)

def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="myPython")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

def login():
    Database()
    ee = Email.get()
    pp = Password.get()
    if ee == "" or pp =="":
        messagebox.showinfo("Alert!","Enter your Email/Password")
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 'email' = %s", [ee])
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            messagebox.showinfo("Alert", "Username already in use")
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `user` (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (str(ee)))
            conn.commit()
            Email.set("")
            Password.set("")
            messagebox.showinfo("Meassage", "Logged in Successfully")
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
Button(root, width=10, height=1, border=0, fg="white", bg="gray", command=login, text="SIGN IN").place(x=135, y=335)
b1=Button(root, width=10, height=1, border=0, fg="white", bg="gray", text="SIGN UP").place(x=135, y=370)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you expect this `get` method to do?

Answer (score 0):

You create `Email` as a `StringVar` but just after you set it to a `Label` object. You probably wanted to *couple* the `StringVar` and the `Label`, as in

```
EmailVar = StringVar()
EmailLabel = Label(root, text='Email/USER ID', font = ('consolas',13))
EmailLabel["textvariable"] = EmailVar
```

Answer (score 0):

You used same variable `Email` for `StringVar` and `Label`, so `Email` will refer to `Label` finally.  Same applies on `Password`.

I think you want to use the `StringVars` in those `Entry` widgets:

```
#============VARIABLES==========
Email = StringVar()
Password = StringVar()
#===============================

# use another name for label
email_lbl = Label(root, text='Email/USER ID', font = ('consolas',13))
email_lbl.place(x=80, y=170)
# use textvariable=Email in Entry(...)
e = Entry(root, width=20, font = ('consolas',13), textvariable=Email)
e.place(x=80, y=200)

# use another name for label
password_lbl = Label(root, text='Password', font = ('consolas',13))
password_lbl.place(x=80, y=230)
# use textvariable=Password in Entry(...)
e1 = Entry(root, width=20, font = ('consolas',13), show = '*', textvariable=Password)
e1.place(x=80, y=260)
```